# Why does the delegate take a parameter when no parameter list is specified?

Tags: c#

The following line of code I cannot completely figure out why that it works.

```
  -->  var blogDelegate = new **Document.SendDoc(blogPoster.PostToBlog);**
```

The **SendDoc has NO parameter** list but still works and I am not certain as to why that is the case. SendDoc is the delegate that returns and int and takes no parameters but in the Example above SendDoc has a parameter of blogPoster.PostToBlog and why does the new keyword have to be used to create a instance of the delegate. This I am not certain of either. I can see creating and instance of the Document but have not seen the reason to create an instance of the delegate method.

**Question: Why does the Document.SendDoc(blogPoster.PostToBlog) have a parameter in the parameter list when the delegate int SendDoc() declaration does not have a parameter list.

---

Code:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.Text = "Document text goes here...";

        var blogPoster   = new BlogPoster();
        var blogDelegate = new Document.SendDoc(blogPoster.PostToBlog);

        doc.ReportSendingResult(blogDelegate);

        var emailSender = new EmailSender();
        var emailDelegate = new Document.SendDoc(emailSender.SendEmail);
        doc.ReportSendingResult(emailDelegate);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
```

---

```
   class Document
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public delegate int SendDoc();

        public void ReportSendingResult(SendDoc sendingDelegate)
        {
            if (sendingDelegate() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to send!");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
  public class EmailSender
  {
    private int sendResult;
    public int SendEmail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Simulating sending email...");
        return sendResult;
    }
  }
```

---

```
  public class BlogPoster
    {
        public int PostToBlog()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Posting to blog...");
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: In what assembly does this `Document` live?  Is this part of MS Office?

Comment: You misunderstand how delegates work.  When you *create* the delegate object then you must provide the target of the delegate.  That argument is not optional, it is the *name* of the method.  When you *call* the delegate then you must provide the target method arguments.  None in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C# language specification, [version 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 7.6.10:

> ### The new operator
>
> The new operator is used to create new instances of types.
>
> There are three forms of new expressions:
>
> - Object creation expressions are used to create new instances of class types and value types.
> - Array creation expressions are used to create new instances of array types.
> - Delegate creation expressions are used to create new instances of delegate types.

You're probably used to seeing `new` used in the context of the first and/or second of these expressions. But in your current code, this is actually the third form:

> A *delegate-creation-expression* is used to create a new instance of a *delegate-type*.
>
> The argument of a delegate creation expression must be a method group, an anonymous function or a value of either the compile time type dynamic or a *delegate-type*. If the argument is a method group, it identifies the method and, for an instance method, the object for which to create a delegate. If the argument is an anonymous function it directly defines the parameters and method body of the delegate target. If the argument is a value it identifies a delegate instance of which to create a copy.

That is, the parameter is identifying which *method* to bind the delegate instance to.

---

From your question:

> why does the new keyword have to be used to create a instance of the delegate

It doesn't. The C# compiler can usually create delegates for you behind the scenes without you having to explicitly create them. You should be able to just write:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Text = "Document text goes here...";

var blogPoster   = new BlogPoster();
doc.ReportSendingResult(blogPoster.PostToBlog);

var emailSender = new EmailSender();
doc.ReportSendingResult(emailSender.SendEmail);
```

This is covered in section 6.6 of the aforementioned language spec.